# Why should you convert a mail based inter-service communication system to a Message based system

Tags: java, email, jmx

We have an old (pre 2004) email based system for sending structured messages between services.

It works, is very robust and takes advantage of email queuing to handle routing, load and backlog should the ingestion program go off line.

It ain't broke, why would we 'fix' it?

Comment: Why indeed? We have no idea.

Comment: I've had plenty of customers using installations more than ten years old. Generally they work fine right up until they don't. Then their maintainers discover that nobody knows how the system works, and it's impossible to get bug fixes for infrastructure components. I'm a big supporter of not fixing things that ain't broke, but I'm concerned that the modern software industry moves too quickly for that to be a good plan in many cases.

Comment: It *is* broken, because email has exactly zero delivery guarantees.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider what would happen if you needed to change it.  If nobody has any idea how to put a change in production, it is a very good time to find out while you have the benefit of the current system working.  If you wait until it breaks, you may not be able to recover the system.

These days, you can capture behavior for future reference and simulate multi-host systems easily on your own machine using container technology like Docker.  If you want to do this I would suggest looking into Docker Compose.  Also use version control.